# SonarLint doesn't see server binding

Tags: intellij-idea, sonarqube, code-inspection, sonarlint

```
IntelliJ IDEA -> Settings -> Other settings -> SonarLint General Settings
```

> SonarQube servers: Localhost (http://localhost:9000; 
>   login: admin; password: admin;
>   test connection - "Authentification successful") Update binding: few seconds ago

```
IntelliJ IDEA -> Settings -> Other settings -> SonarLint Project Settings
```

> Bind to server: Localhost SonarQube project: **Update server binding
>   first**

But it's already bound! What may be wrong? Web interface also can't see the project.

When I press `Analize code with SonarLint` in workspace, I get an error popup: "*Project bound to invalid SonarQube server. Please, check configuration*"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Go to http://localhost:9000

Then go to administration

Then go to projects management

Then press create project, enter project name exactly like in your IDE.

Then  go to

> IntelliJ IDEA -> Settings -> Other settings -> SonarLint Project
>   Settings Bind to server:

Press refresh binding.

That's it.

Comment: So simple. is it needed to run analysis? or I may run without connection to remote server?

Comment: You can't, remote server is what doing analysis, not ide plugin doing it

Comment: i gave same  name  and  key as  master  still says  project isnt  intialized on sonar  server :(

Comment: In SonarLint 4.2.0, there is no "Refresh binding" action any more. It has been replaced with: IntelliJ IDEA > Settings > Other Settings > SonarLint General Settings, button Update binding.

Answer (score 0):

In my case:

1. Go to administrator panel on localhost:9000
2. Go to marketplace and search "typescript"
3. Update your "SonarTS - Code Analyzer for TypeScript" (just push the button)
   Thats all. Don't forget restart your server